# Tabs and Category Widget

Tags: widgets, tabs

I need some help with tabs in Wordpress. I tried several tab plugins for Wordpress, but none did what I wont. I tried Quick tabs, Hybrid tabs and SidebarTabs.

I want sidebar to be like this: http://www4.slikomat.com/11/0116/q7a-tabs.png

In fact these are basic tabs, with possibility to put content in it.

Another question is about displaying news from some category in widget on sidebar.

I want to display it with thumbnail and title with link to that news. I want it to be like on this picture : http://www4.slikomat.com/11/0116/lpr-kat.png

So can you recommend some plugin for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tabber Tabs Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tabber-tabs-widget/)
I'd been looking around as well, and this one seems to fit the goal. And no coding, all done with plugin/widget.